# How to address Gmock with Symbol not found error?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I was trying to make a minimal gmock test case from [donsoft.io's example](http://donsoft.io/gmock-presentation/#/3/16)

The file structure is simple:

```
my_workspace/
├── BUILD
├── WORKSPACE
├── coinflipper.cc
├── coinflipper.h
├── mockrng.cc
├── mockrng.h
└── rng.h
```

I got this error while trying to compile by  `$ bazel test --test_output=all //:mockrng`

```
$ bazel test --test_output=all //:mockrng
INFO: Analyzed target //:mockrng (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 test target...
FAIL: //:mockrng (see /private/var/tmp/_bazel_pvd/83a142a3c9781856c99d4f0c60c1af76/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/mockrng/test.log)
INFO: From Testing //:mockrng:
==================== Test output for //:mockrng:
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZTI3Rng
  Referenced from: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_pvd/83a142a3c9781856c99d4f0c60c1af76/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/21/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/mockrng.runfiles/__main__/mockrng
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /private/var/tmp/_bazel_pvd/83a142a3c9781856c99d4f0c60c1af76/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/21/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/mockrng.runfiles/__main__/mockrng
================================================================================
Target //:mockrng up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/mockrng
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.256s, Critical Path: 0.13s
INFO: 2 processes: 2 darwin-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed, 1 test FAILED, 2 total actions
//:mockrng                                                               FAILED in 0.1s
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_pvd/83a142a3c9781856c99d4f0c60c1af76/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/mockrng/test.log

INFO: Build completed, 1 test FAILED, 2 total actions
```

My code were basically the same as donsoft.io, just wondering if there anything that I had missed?

#### coinflipper.cc

```c
#include "coinflipper.h"

CoinFlipper::CoinFlipper(Rng* rng) : d_rng(rng) {}

CoinFlipper::Result CoinFlipper::flipCoin() const {
  const double val = d_rng->generate(0.0, 1.0);
  return (val < 0.5) ? HEADS : TAILS;
}
```

#### coinflipper.h

```c
#include "rng.h"

class CoinFlipper {
 private:
  Rng* d_rng;  // held, not owned

 public:
  enum Result { HEADS = 0, TAILS = 1 };

  explicit CoinFlipper(Rng* rng);
  Result flipCoin() const;
};
```

#### mockrng.cc

```c
#include "mockrng.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "coinflipper.h"

TEST(CoinFlipper, ShouldReturnHeadsIfRandValueIsLessThanProbability) {    
    MockRng rng;
    
    EXPECT_CALL(rng, generate(::testing::DoubleEq(0.0), ::testing::DoubleEq(1.0)))
        .Times(::testing::Exactly(1))
        .WillOnce(::testing::Return(0.25));

    CoinFlipper coinFlipper(&rng);
    CoinFlipper::Result result = coinFlipper.flipCoin();
    EXPECT_EQ(CoinFlipper::HEADS, result);    
}
```

#### mockrng.h

```c
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "rng.h"

class MockRng : public Rng {
  public:
    MOCK_METHOD2(generate, double(double, double));
};
```

#### rng.h

```c
#ifndef RNG_H
#define RNG_H
class Rng {
 public:
  virtual ~Rng();
  virtual double generate(double min, double max) = 0;
};
#endif
```

#### BUILD

```py
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_test")

cc_test(
  name = "mockrng",
  size = "small",
  srcs = ["mockrng.cc", "mockrng.h", "rng.h","coinflipper.h","coinflipper.cc"],
  deps = ["@com_google_googletest//:gtest_main"],
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition part for `Rng::~Rng()` is missing, a slightly fix will work:

```cpp
#ifndef RNG_H
#define RNG_H
class Rng {
 public:
  virtual ~Rng() {};
  virtual double generate(double min, double max) = 0;
};
#endif
```

By the way, what version of the compiler are you using? A modern compiler will give us explicit error message:

```
undefined reference to `Rng::~Rng()'
```

Rather than the one you get:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZTI3Rng
```

Some irrelevant suggestions：
Some header files are missing a guard processor, it's error-prone and needs to be fixed.

Comment: `$ cc --version` got `Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)`

Comment: @pvd This is very surprising, clang 12 is the very latest compiler, or it's the problem with the linker.

Comment: I just kicked off another thread on gmock, by any chance, would you help to take a look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67934510/how-to-mock-non-virtual-methods-in-concrete-classes-using-gmock