# How to mock Non-virtual Methods in concrete classes using gmock?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I somehow extended the gmock test case from [donsoft.io's example](http://donsoft.io/gmock-presentation/#/3/16), and made it as follows:

```
coinflipper/
├── BUILD
├── WORKSPACE
├── coinflipper.cc
├── coinflipper.h
├── rng.cc
└── rng.h
```

Well, instead put the `Rng` class as a parameter of the constructor of the `CoinFlipper`, I made it initialized inside the `CoinFlipper::flipCoin()` method.

I was wondering how to mock the `generate()` from `Rng` in this case?

#### coinflipper.cc

```c
#include "coinflipper.h"
#include <iostream>

CoinFlipper::CoinFlipper() {}

CoinFlipper::Result CoinFlipper::flipCoin() const {
  Rng d_rng;
  const double val = d_rng.generate(0.0, 1.0);
  return (val < 0.5) ? HEADS : TAILS;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  CoinFlipper cf;
  CoinFlipper::Result res = cf.flipCoin();
  if (res == 0) {
      std::cout << "head" << std::endl;
  } else {
      std::cout << "tail" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

#### coinflipper.h

```c
#include "rng.h"

class CoinFlipper {
 public:
  enum Result { HEADS = 0, TAILS = 1 };

  explicit CoinFlipper();
  Result flipCoin() const;
};
```

#### rng.h

```c
#ifndef RNG_H
#define RNG_H
class Rng {
 public:
  Rng() {};
  ~Rng() {};
  double generate(double min, double max);
};
#endif
```

#### rng.cc

```c
#include "rng.h"

double Rng::generate(double min, double max) {    
    return 0.75; //Just for test
}
```

#### BUILD

```py
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_binary", "cc_library")

cc_library(
    name = "rng",
    srcs = ["rng.cc"],
    hdrs = ["rng.h"],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "coinflipper",
    srcs = ["coinflipper.cc", "coinflipper.h"],    
    deps = [
        ":rng",
    ],
)

cc_test(
  name = "coinflipper_test",
  size = "small",
  srcs = ["coinflipper_test.cc", "rng.h","coinflipper.h","coinflipper.cc"],
  deps = ["@com_google_googletest//:gtest_main"],
)
```

#### coinflipper_test.cc

```c
#include "coinflipper.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

class MockRng {
 public:  
  MOCK_METHOD2(generate, double(double, double));
};

TEST(CoinFlipper, ShouldReturnHeadsIfRandValueIsLessThanProbability) {
  MockRng rng;
  EXPECT_CALL(rng, generate(::testing::DoubleEq(0.0), ::testing::DoubleEq(1.0)))
      .Times(::testing::Exactly(1))
      .WillOnce(::testing::Return(0.25));

  CoinFlipper coinFlipper;
  auto result = coinFlipper.flipCoin<MockRng>(rng);
  EXPECT_EQ(CoinFlipper::HEADS, result);
}
```

Bazel output:

```
$ bazel test --test_output=all //:coinflipper_test
DEBUG: Rule 'rules_cc' indicated that a canonical reproducible form can be obtained by modifying arguments sha256 = "56ac9633c13d74cb71e0546f103ce1c58810e4a76aa8325da593ca4277908d72"
DEBUG: Repository rules_cc instantiated at:
  /Users/pvd/Downloads/toys/cpp/bazelgtest/coinflipper/WORKSPACE:9:13: in <toplevel>
Repository rule http_archive defined at:
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_pvd/3077b447e558b1418694504407cbcb45/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:336:31: in <toplevel>
DEBUG: Rule 'com_google_googletest' indicated that a canonical reproducible form can be obtained by modifying arguments sha256 = "5cf189eb6847b4f8fc603a3ffff3b0771c08eec7dd4bd961bfd45477dd13eb73"
DEBUG: Repository com_google_googletest instantiated at:
  /Users/pvd/Downloads/toys/cpp/bazelgtest/coinflipper/WORKSPACE:3:13: in <toplevel>
Repository rule http_archive defined at:
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_pvd/3077b447e558b1418694504407cbcb45/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:336:31: in <toplevel>
INFO: Analyzed target //:coinflipper_test (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 test target...
FAIL: //:coinflipper_test (see /private/var/tmp/_bazel_pvd/3077b447e558b1418694504407cbcb45/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/coinflipper_test/test.log)
INFO: From Testing //:coinflipper_test:
==================== Test output for //:coinflipper_test:
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __ZN3Rng8generateEdd
  Referenced from: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_pvd/3077b447e558b1418694504407cbcb45/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/72/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/coinflipper_test.runfiles/__main__/coinflipper_test
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN3Rng8generateEdd
  Referenced from: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_pvd/3077b447e558b1418694504407cbcb45/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/72/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/coinflipper_test.runfiles/__main__/coinflipper_test
  Expected in: flat namespace

================================================================================
Target //:coinflipper_test up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/coinflipper_test
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.429s, Critical Path: 0.14s
INFO: 2 processes: 2 darwin-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed, 1 test FAILED, 2 total actions
//:coinflipper_test                                                      FAILED in 0.1s
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_pvd/3077b447e558b1418694504407cbcb45/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/coinflipper_test/test.log

INFO: Build completed, 1 test FAILED, 2 total actions
```

Comment: We need run `bazel clean ` then `bazel test -s --test_output=all //:coinflipper_test` to get verbose message

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin https://gist.github.com/impvd/d2c1691a2e42582de46160cd96591cb0

Comment: The `cc_test` part have missed the dependency of `:rng`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define dependencies(The random generator here) as local variables are not recommended, it's much harder to do dependencies injection(Or it won't be possible), so I change the functions `Rng_t` into template function and pass the Rng as a parameter.

In practice to construct a random generation may be heavy work, it needs to initialize its internal status, to construct it every time we call the function `flipCoin` is waste.

The non-virtual function can be mocked, one most commonly used strategy is to use the template, here we make the class CoinFlipper's member function as a template function, then we can test the dependency with our `MockRng`.

Be aware that for the template function, we need to define the member function in the header file.

coinflipper.h:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "rng.h"

class CoinFlipper {
 public:
  enum Result { HEADS = 0, TAILS = 1 };

  template <typename Rng_t>
  Result flipCoin(Rng_t& rng) {
    const double val = rng.generate(0.0, 1.0);
    return (val < 0.5) ? HEADS : TAILS;
  }
};
```

The test file part, `MockRng` doesn't inherit anything now. And the test member function we use here has the type `CoinFlipper::flipCoin<MockRng>`. For production code: we  use the type `CoinFlipper::flipCoin<Rng>`

```cpp
//#include "mockrng.h"

#include "coinflipper.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

class MockRng {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD2(generate, double(double, double));
};

TEST(CoinFlipper, ShouldReturnHeadsIfRandValueIsLessThanProbability) {
  MockRng rng;
  EXPECT_CALL(rng, generate(::testing::DoubleEq(0.0), ::testing::DoubleEq(1.0)))
      .Times(::testing::Exactly(1))
      .WillOnce(::testing::Return(0.25));

  CoinFlipper coinFlipper;
  auto result = coinFlipper.flipCoin<MockRng>(rng);
  EXPECT_EQ(CoinFlipper::HEADS, result);
}
```

See related question here:

[Mock non-virtual method C++ (gmock)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777733/mock-non-virtual-method-c-gmock)

The official document:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/googletest/+/refs/tags/release-1.8.0/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md

Comment: There're slightly different with the minimal test case before,  instead put the `Rng` class as a parameter of the constructor of the CoinFlipper, I made it initialized inside the `CoinFlipper::flipCoin()` method

Comment: @pvd I have updated the answer, I think to init the out dependency as a local variable is not applicable.

Comment: Your code looks find, however, I got the same error again `dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __ZN3Rng8generateEdd`

Comment: @pvd The missing symbol is `Rng::generate`, it belongs to the library `rng`, I haven't found anything wrong in your Bazel BUILD file, man be you need to paste the Bazel build output message here.

Comment: Actually maybe we could mock them by `mprotect`, I just kicked off an issue in https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/3441 and described some details there.

Comment: @pvd Seems interesting, `mprotect` is used to set protection on a region of memory, I can't imagine how can it used for mocking.  Please wait for the issues responding.

Comment: So sad that Google rejected it.

Comment: @pvd The `mprotect` way is just hacking, it hasn't been proven to be stable and ready for production usage.

Comment: But it did kind of widely used right now, like 500 stars subhook: https://github.com/Zeex/subhook

Comment: @pvd I think the idea is somewhat good, but the implementation has several limitations and no correctness guarantees, I think it would be better to write compiler tools to replace the dependencies calls, it would be stable.

Comment: You may also spawn an issue to ask how many productions are using that library to gain confidence.